# how to select table cell for exact textContent

Tags: jquery, contains

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td:contains('1')").addClass('isOne');
});
```

I tried above code, but it also selects `11` or `111` or anything which contains 1.

But I want only the cells having `1` as exact content to be selected

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").each(function() {  
        if($(this).text() === "1") {
            $(this).addClass('isOne');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nHtvL/2/

Comment: Tip: Save `$(this)` in a variable for a small performance boost. It will become very noticeable in a loop consisting of many cells.

Comment: isn't there any other way without looping?

Comment: Sorry dude I am not sure about any such way. I will  try to find out and if i get i will post here.

Comment: this itself has just three lines why are you looking for a method without loop???

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: because I hate loops.. ;-)

Comment: ha ha.. sometime we got to do the things even we don't like.. by the way there will always be loops either we do it explicitly or the plugin will do it implicitly, can't scape from loops :)

Answer (score 2):

TRY

```
 $("#mytable td").each(function() {
    if($(this).html() == '1') { $(this).addClass('isOne'); }
 });
```

**[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/HhN8H/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the table's id. Otherwise, the code will select all cells in all tables on your page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tableid td").each(function(){    
    var $td = $(this); 
    if($td.text() == "1"){
       $td.addClass('isOne');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is derived from `dku.rajkumar`'s,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:contains('1')").each(function() {  
        var $dis = $(this);
        if($dis.text() == "1") {
            $dis.addClass('isOne');
        }
    });
});
```

I edited his original post, but was rejected. So improving his answer here.